# Adding Components from Gluon SceneBuilder to Java Fx

Tags: java, maven, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm using JavaFx 11 with the Gluon SceneBuilder. 
I wanted to use the Avatar (Gluon Object) in JavaFx and after adding GluoCharm as libary the Avatar icon was just black. I then updated from Version 4 to 6 but now i'm facing a new problem.

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.gluonhq.attach.util not found, required by com.gluonhq.charm.glisten
```

I added everything to my module-info and update the pom.xml from Maven.

```
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.gluonhq.charm.glisten;
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Workspace</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gluon-nexus-repository</id>
            <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Still same error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I didn't use Maven at the beginning just added it duo to another stack overflow answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Gluon Mobile in your desktop app? It has a commercial license, and it is designed to be used with `MobileApplication`.

Comment: The longer i think about it the less i want it. I guess if I get it to run, there will be more problems later, just for a couple of components.